# How to read .csv lines in an automated sequence

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver

I'm a novice to programming and have been writing a script using `selenium.webdriver`, `pyautogui` and `csv` that sequentially opens up .pdf files on the browser and saves them to a directory.

I have a single-column .csv file that includes all links I want to open and download, which looks like this:

```
https://example.com/1.pdf
https://example.com/2.pdf
https://example.com/3.pdf
https://example.com/4.pdf
```

However, I cannot figure out how to make a loop for the script to read the first line in the .csv, run my saving sequence, and then go to the second line, execute my sequence again, etc., all the way to the last line.

This is my saving sequence that runs without a problem.

```
driver.get('https://example.com/1.pdf')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

I tried to make a changing variable for each line so that the `driver.get()` function would read incrementally, but I couldn't get it to work. I managed to make it print individual lines with this command:

```
with open('C:\\path\file.csv') as fp:
    line = fp.readlines()
    print(line[1])
```

However, I can't figure out the logic for a loop to incrementally raise the value in `line[]` to go to `line[1]`, `line[2]`, `line[3]`, etc. inside the `driver.get()` sequence.

Thank you for your help :^E

Comment: Try `for line in file`.

Comment: If you're wondering how to read a `.csv` file, you should take a look to the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents). It's part of Python's standard library so, you should already have it in your system.